# Is there any way for the user to decide the polygon that he wants to draw by using opengl in c++?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-compat

im using opengl in codeblocks to make one project.I want to build first a polygon with n peaks,but those n peaks i want them to be declared by a user.
My code so far:

```
 #include<GL/glut.h>
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 void init(void){
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gluOrtho2D (0.0,640.0,0.0,480.0);
 }

 void polygon(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);

    int p1[]={200,100};
    int p2[]={400,100};
    int p3[]={550,300};
    int p4[]={400,480};
    int p5[]={200,480};
    int p6[]={50,300};

    glBegin (GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2iv (p1);
    glVertex2iv (p2);
    glVertex2iv (p3);
    glVertex2iv (p4);
    glVertex2iv (p5);
    glVertex2iv (p6);
    glEnd ( );

    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc,char** argv){
    int peaks = 0;
    printf("Give the number of your peaks that you want to draw: ");
    scanf("%d",&peaks);

   glutInit(&argc,argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowPosition(500,200);
   glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
   glutCreateWindow("Internal Checkpoints");
   init();
   glutDisplayFunc(polygon);
   glutMainLoop();
}
```

In main im reading how many peaks a user wants, but i cant send it to my polygon function cause glutDisplayFunc want as argument a void func.Also i cant use a scanf in my polygon function because it makes some problems when i run it.
So, is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

You could make your `peaks` variable global. That would make it accessible in your polygon function. If this is just a toy program, this is your best solution.

---

## Edit

Alright, so reading over the glut documentation, it appears that you should not use the [glutDisplayFunc](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node46.html#SECTION00081000000000000000) to generate new geometry. Also GLUT is rather old.

You may want to look at [SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) as a better opengl wrapper. It doesn't depend on callbacks like glut, and you have a main render loop. It also has a nice [vertex array](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-vertex-array.php) class you can use to make polygons.

I have no affiliation with SFML, it's just the graphics and multimedia library I am most familiar with.

Comment: Ok thank you very much you helped me a lot.I think that i cant use SFML cause my homework is glut based only

Comment: @ΣωτηρηςΙωαννιδης Glut is a bit of a beast. I'm surprised anyone is still teaching it. It also looks like they're teaching old opengl. Let me know if you want to talk more. I miss taking graphics in college.

Comment: thank you, If i have other problem I will appreciate your answers a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Function glutDisplayFunc as you said expects a function pointer as it's parameter. 
The only way to use variables in that callback, are global variables or static variables of class.

As mentioned above SFML is  great wrapper of Open Gl and I recommended it.